# Checking which of the modules is the closest

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Welcome. My problem is that I have given an array of numbers which I need to calculate the average (that part I did), but then I have to find the array element (module), which is closer to the average. Below paste the code (a form of main () imposed)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double* aver(double* arr, size_t size, double& average){

    double count;
    for(int p = 0; p < size; p++)
        count += arr[p];
        count /= size;

        double * pointer;
        pointer = &count;
        average = *pointer;     
}

int main() { 
    double arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7}; 
    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    double average = 0; 
    double* p = aver(arr,size,average); 
    cout << p << " " << average << endl; 
}
```

The program should give a result

4 3.66667

I have no idea how to check which element is nearest to another, and substitute it into *p

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Don't indent like that, it gives the (erroneous) impression that everything in `aver` after the `for` is part of the loop. Even though white space is not meaningful to a C++ compiler, it **is** to humans.

Comment: Looks like basic arithmetic to me. The average is closest to 4 as you suggest; why? Because (4 - yourAverage) < (yourAverage - 3).

Comment: "* I have no idea how to check which element is nearest to another, and substitute it into p"  Give it a bit of a think.  If you want to be a programmer, you're going to have to figure stuff like this out.

Comment: As @syam said you should intend your code properly. And even though single line for, while, if are allowed without bracket don't use them. Always use the version with curl brackets.

Your code for setting the average value is overly complicated, you don't need to create another pointer for this it can be done in one line.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I know how to find out which number is closest to the modul, but I still have trouble with understanding pointers. Can you tell me how to reduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everybody is doing the kids homework...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double min(double first, double second){
  return first < second ? first : second;
}

double abs(double first){
  return 0 < first ? first : -first;
}


double* aver(double* arr, size_t size, double& average){

    double count;
    for(int p = 0; p < size; p++)
      count += arr[p];

    average = count/size;

    int closest_index = 0;
    for(int p = 0; p < size; p++)
      if( abs(arr[p] - average) < 
          abs(arr[closest_index] - average) )
        closest_index = p;

    return &arr[closest_index];
}

int main() { 
    double arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7}; 
    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    double average = 0; 
    double* p = aver(arr,size,average); 
    cout << *p << " " << average << endl; 
    //Above ^^ gives the expected behavior, 
    //Without it you'll get nothing but random memory
}
```

I insist that you need the * before the p, it gives the value that the pointer is pointing too. Without the * then the value is the address of the memory location, which is indeterminate in this case. Ask your professor/teacher whether the specification is correct, because it isn't.

Try and understand the style and functions involved - it isn't complicated, and writing like this can go a long ways to making your graders job easier.

Also that interface is a very leaky one, in real work - consider some of the standard library algorithms and containers instead.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm is based on the fact that `std::map` keeps its elements sorted (using `operator<`):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double closest_to_avg(double* arr, size_t size, double avg) {
  std::map<double,double> disturbances;
  for(int p = 0; p < size; p++) {
        disturbances[fabs(avg-arr[p])]=arr[p]; //if two elements are equally
  }                                            //distant from avg we take
  return disturbances.begin()->second;         //a new one
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help a lot, but i cant change anything in main() and in structure of double* aver(double* arr, size_t size, double& average){i can work only with this part}

Comment: @Daniel Zawadzki so move this code into your function, you have everything what needed already computed, just create this map in your function, do this loop, and return disturbances.begin()->second;

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is not the answer to your problem, since you already got couple of them

How about trying something new ?

Use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) to achieve same goal.

```
#include<algorithm>
//...
struct comp
{
    double avg;
    comp(double x):avg(x){}

    bool operator()(const double &x) const
    {
        return x < avg;
    }   
};

std::sort(arr,arr+size);
average =std::accumulate(arr, arr+size, 0.0) / size;
double *p= std::partition(arr, arr+size, comp(average));

std::cout<<"Average :"<<average <<" Closest : "<<*p<<std::endl;
```