# Calculating average then returning the closest element in array to the average

Tags: c++, arrays, average

I suppose to calculate the average in the array of doubles then return the value of the closest element in the array to the calculated average. But the algorithm I used is O(2n). Is it possible to determine the closest element to the average while still calculating average?

I think no.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double* aver(double* arr, size_t size, double& average){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        average+=arr[i];
    average/=size;
    double* ret = arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(abs(arr[i] - average) < abs(*ret -  average)){
            *ret = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    double arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    double average = 0;
    double* p = aver(arr, size, average);
    cout<< *p << " " << average << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whether the array will be in sorted order? if it is then we can optimise our loop

Comment: There may be a clever trick to get both the average and the closest element to the average in one pass, but it probably does not make any kind of real performance difference, as O(n) and O(2n) are the same thing.

Comment: Did you check the other answers of this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/19504289/1151831

Answer (score 0):

You can find an element closest to a target with a trivial O(logn) binary search if the array is sorted. If it's not sorted, then it's a linear search.

As a side note, O(2n) might make intuitive sense, but mathematically speaking it's no different than O(n).